# Using JDT: How can I find out if a method is overriding another method

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I am traversing an AST using a JDT ASTVisitor.

```
private void removeOverrideAnnotations(CompilationUnit astUnit) {
    astUnit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration methodDeclarationNode) {
            if (isOverridingMethodOfSuperclass(methodDeclarationNode)) {
                ... process ...
            }
            return super.visit(methodDeclarationNode);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I find out if the MethodDeclaration I am visiting is overriding a superclass method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below link for an overrride method search. Basically it does an exhaustive search on the project, finds the superclasses of a Type and checks each method with superclass method for the same name and arguments.

- https://gist.github.com/shivamkalra/3197033

Comment: Thanks. The tipp to compare the erasures in line 105 was also very helpfull.

Comment: The gist is no longer available. Why wasn't it copy pasted as the solution?